# Expression Trees as Binary Trees

Tags: java, expression, expression-trees

I have a simple question.

Why all expression trees are modeled as "Binary Trees" and not as 'N ary trees' ?

Is there any reason why an expression cannot be modeled using N-ary tree?

Comment: Sure they can... but all n-ary trees can be modeled as binary trees, so why bother with the extra complexity?

Comment: So does that mean expression trees can also be done using n ary trees? Because wherever I read about expression trees I see only binary tree examples.

Comment: They could be, but it's not necessary in most cases, depending on the types of expression trees you're dealing with.  If you don't have to use n-ary trees, then why bother?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, Sorry I didn understand completely.

Comment: What types of expressions are we talking about, and why would you need the full generality of n-ary trees?

Comment: Of interest; [Every Binary Tree There Is](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/19/every-binary-tree-there-is/) A series of articles on converting expressions to binary trees.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good reasons why expression trees are often binary:

1. The most common expression trees represent arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) or logical predicates (`AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `XOR`). There are all binary (and unary) operations, so binary trees make the most sense. You *could* have for example n-ary `+`, but that just complicates things without good reason.
2. From a more theoretical perspective, if you have an n-ary tree, you can represent it using an equivalent binary tree without losing anything. Using the n-ary `+` example the following trees (one n-ary and one binary) could be considered the same:

   ```
     +       +
    /|\     / \
   a b c   +   c
          / \
         a   b
   ```

On the other hand, there are libraries that use n-ary expression trees where they make sense. For example, C# expression trees (from the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace) use n-ary trees for invocation expressions. So, the expression `f(a, b, c)` would be represented as `InvocationExpression` that looks like this:

```
  f
 /|\
a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why all expression trees are modeled as "Binary Trees" and not as 'N ary trees' ?

They aren't. Expression tree internal nodes are operators, and operators can be unary, binary, or ternary at least, maybe more.

> Is there any reason why an expression cannot be modeled using N-ary tree?

They are.

Comment: Can you please say what are the reasons u are talking about?